# What's the correct terminology for + email alias?

Tags: email, alias, terminology

I'm trying to find a email host that supports aliases in the form of hello+world@yourdomain.com that will automatically send to hello@yourdomain.com.  I know that Google Apps and Office365 both seem to support this, but for personal use, I'm trying to find a cheaper, optimally free, solution.  However, I'm trying to find the correct terminology for this type of alias so that I can search for it instead of emailing every potential host with examples of the type of alias I'm looking for.

Is there a specific term for this? Google's [page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/12096?hl=en) on this seems to be very generic and doesn't really help when I try to search for an alternative.

Comment: I'm not sure of the proper term for it, but for free use, regular gmail supports it (user+foo@gmail.com).
FWIW, Gmail also ignores periods, so foo.bar@gmail and foobar@gmail route to the same account.
See http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html

Comment: I know that regular gmail supports it, but I want it for addresses at my own domain, which is only available through Google Apps, which is a business product.  While the cost is relatively light for a business, it's not really suited for personal use and maintaining several accounts for your family IMO.  Google and Microsoft both used to have free services, and I'm still on as a legacy for Microsoft's service, but I no longer have the ability to manage accounts on my domain, which is becoming problematic.

Comment: If you are looking for a webhosting service that has this, look for "unlimited email addresses" which means they'll support forwarders which can be used as aliasses. Also Catch-all can be used for this if you don't want to head into your control panel each time you want to make an alias.

Comment: To add to the answers below, the name for this on qmail MTAs is “[extension address](http://www.lifewithqmail.org/lwq.html#extension-addresses).”

Comment: I run my own mail server (for multiple domains) on a $5/mo linode.com VPS.  Set up `postfix+dovecot` wtih a `mysql` back end.  On my system I simply set the `recipient_delimiter` option.  I set it to a hyphen `-` on mine, because I've noticed that the outlook web client doesn't always honor the + when sending

Answer (score 12, accepted):

###What's the correct terminology for + email alias?

It has a variety of names, including **Sub-addressing**, **Detailed Addressing** or **SMTP Tags**.

---

[RFC 5233 - Sieve Email Filtering: Subaddress Extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5233):

> **Abstract**

> On email systems that allow for 'subaddressing' or 'detailed
> addressing' (e.g., "ken+sieve@example.org"), it is sometimes
> desirable to make comparisons against these sub-parts of addresses.
> This document defines an extension to the Sieve Email Filtering
> Language that allows users to compare against the user and detail
> sub-parts of an address.

---

###Sub-addressing

> Some mail services support a tag appended to the local part, such that
> the modified address is an alias to the unmodified address. For
> example, the address `joeuser+tag@example.com` denotes the same
> delivery address as `joeuser@example.com`. The text of the tag may be
> used to apply filtering, or to create single-use addresses.
>
> Some IETF standards-track documents, such as RFC 5233, refer to this
> convention as sub-addressing. However, the automatic form validation
> of many web sites rejects `+` as a valid character in the email
> address.
>
> Some service providers are inconsistent, and use address tags in their
> own outbound email, but disallow address tags for users.
>
> Disposable email addresses of this form, using various separators
> between the base name and the tag, are supported by several email
> services, including Runbox (plus), Gmail (plus), Yahoo! Mail Plus
> (hyphen), Apple's iCloud (plus), Outlook.com (plus), FastMail
> (plus and Subdomain Addressing), and MMDF (equals).
>
> Most installations of the qmail and Courier Mail Server products
> support the use of a hyphen `-` as a separator within the local-part,
> such as `joeuser-tag@example.com` or
> `joeuser-tag-sub-anything-else@example.com`. This allows qmail through
> .qmail-default or .qmail-tag-sub-anything-else files to sort, filter,
> forward, or run an application based on the tagging system
> established.
>
> Postfix allows configuring an arbitrary separator from the legal
> character set. The separator info remains available on the email
> (address is not rewritten to remove it), and thus is useful in
> internal mail-routing, filtering, and forwarding via any of the
> mechanisms existing in Postfix.

Source [Email address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Sub-addressing)

Comment: I noticed a typo -- RFC52*2*3 -- but of course the editor won't let me make changes smaller than 6 characters :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there's a single standard name for it; I've seen different email programs/services refer to it by different names.  The most common ones I've seen are:
- Plus-addressing
- Sub-addressing
- Address tags

The 1st is probably the oldest (in my experience), and what I still refer to it as; the last seems to be more in vogue now.

Comment: (Insufficient reputation to comment on original post)  AFAIK, Office365 does NOT support ad-hoc tags; the only way to use "+" in an address is to explicitly make an alias.  If anyone knows how to enable adhoc tagging, I'd love to know, for the loss of this feature was one of many downgrades that we suffered when the current IT admins moved from our old Postfix server to Office365.

Comment: If it doesn't work on Office365, then it must have been a downgrade since Live Domain Emails.  I have that right now and I tested again just to make sure I wasn't going crazy, but it does work as expected and I received the message.  As far as I know, this has been working for me out of the box, but I suppose they must've changed something in Office365.

Comment: @CharlesBoling It doesn't work on Exchange either apparently. This answer [Can you configure MS Exchange to support the gmail "+keyword" trick?](http://serverfault.com/a/201336) on ServerFault suggests it could be done with some clever scripting ...